# Haproxy with istio-ingressgateway as SSL backend

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, istio, envoyproxy

Initialy i test with mode tcp and that works. The haproxy tcp passthru config is below:

```
frontend https_in
        bind *:443
        mode tcp
        option forwardfor
        option tcplog
        log global
        default_backend https_backend

backend https_backend
        mode tcp
        server s1 10.21.0.60:31390 check
        server s2 10.21.0.169:31390 check
        server s3 10.21.0.173:31390 check
```

How should a mode http configuration look like? I need to decrypt traffic, inject some headers (like forwarded-for) and encrypt it again, sending it to ssl istio ingress-gateway backend.

My configuration attempts were many (and unsuccessful) here is one snapshot:

```
frontend https_in
    mode http
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/prod.pem crt /etc/haproxy/dev.pem crt /etc/haproxy/stg.pem no-sslv3

    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443

    rspadd  Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=15768000

    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
    acl acl_app1 req_ssl_sni -i mydomain.test
    use_backend https_backend if acl_app1

backend https_backend
    mode http
    server s1 10.21.0.60:31390 check ssl verify none
```

In haproxy logs i see

```
haproxy[12734]: Server https_backend/s1 is DOWN, reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure (Connection reset by peer)", check duration: 1ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
haproxy[12734]: Server https_backend/s1 is DOWN, reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure (Connection reset by peer)", check duration: 1ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
haproxy[12734]: backend https_backend has no server available!
```

If i remove the check, and still try to query haproxy:

```
haproxy[13381]: https_in~ https_in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

I cannot figure the SNI settings to pass from haproxy into istio to make it work.

I cannot find anything usefull in logs from envoyproxy and istio-ingressgateway on debug loglevel either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since you posted this problem, but I encountered the same issue. So I was able to verify the HAProxy error using the `openssl s_client` command.

`openssl s_client -connect ip:port` would return a `write:errno=104` which means it's a `Connection reset by peer` error.

But when I supplied the server name, I was able to successfully connect to the backend: `openssl s_client -connect ip:port -servername server.name`.

After digging around in the backend option from HAProxy, I stumbled on the [check-sni](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#5.2-check-sni) option, which mentions:

> This option allows you to specify the SNI to be used when doing health checks
> over SSL. It is only possible to use a string to set . ...

So I use this option to configure the backend server as follows

```
server lokomotive-contour ip:port ssl verify none check-sni server.name sni str(server.name) check
```

The critical part is the `check-sni` option like mentioned before; this configures the SNI during the health checks.

But I also found the `sni str()` option to be necessary for getting the regular traffic routing through this backend to work properly.

ps: make sure you are on HAProxy 1.8 or later since the `check-sni` is only supported starting from 1.8

Hope my answer can help you in the future

Comment: I award you a golden shovel. I solved the problem, or istio-ingress solved it for me really, by lacking a metric ton of "regular ingress features". Right now i am using entire istio-service-mesh package (mtls, jaeger, lots of mtls origination and egressgatway) but i dropped the ingress-gateway (as it was goddamn useless and problematic). My entrypoint is: haproxy (tcp, only for proxyprotocol) -> firewall/internal-network-cross-> k8s-nginx-controller (injected with istio sidecar)

Comment: Thank you! After many unsuccessful error searches, this helped me with a similar problem which had nothing to do with Istio. In my case an IIS server was also requiring the SNI to complete the SSL handshake for the check. Two shovels for you, sir!